# How do I pass JSON data for a post request in Python?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to execute a cURL command with Python's Requests module but the server keeps returning response code 406 with the message 'Invalid JSON data'. Below is the cURL command as well as the Python code.

**cURL**

```
curl --data "userDetails={'userEmail':'jon.snow@example.com','org_id': '3$$4bjnNP','fName': 'Jon','lName': 'Snow','jobTitle': 'Night's Watch', 'language': 'Andal(Westeros)','userAccessView': 'Both','start_date': '30-Jan-2017','end_date': '29-Jan-2018','never_exp': false}" --cacert "C:\Users\cthakor\Desktop\User Creation\security.cer" --cookie "ASessionID='GQa3GTlLGZ8mGNH67CQvTvAz='" https://www.example.com/api/portal/createUser
```

**Python**

```
session_id_cookie = {'ASessionID': 'GQa3GTlLGZ8mGNH67CQvTvAz='}
new_user_data = {"userDetails":{
                            "userEmail" : "jsnow@example.com",
                            "org_id" : "3$$4bjnNP",
                            "fName" : "Jon",
                            "lName" : "Snow",
                            "jobTitle": "Night's Watch",
                            "language" : "Andal(Westeros)",
                            "userAccessView" : "Both",
                            "start_date" : "30-Jan-2017",
                            "end_date" : "29-Jan-2018",
                            "never_exp" : False,
                            }
                        }

r = requests.post("https://www.example.com/api/portal/createUser",
                     data=new_user_data, cookies=session_id_cookie)
```

Comment: Use `data=new_user_data['userDetails']`

Comment: use `json = new_user_data`, instead of `data = new_user_data`

Comment: akashkarothiya & Clearer that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with `'jobTitle': 'Night's Watch'`. Instead use `"jobTitle": "Night's Watch"` or you can escape the single quote with slash, `'jobTitle': 'Night\'s Watch'`

Comment: Nope, if you use double quotes to wrap your string in Python then you can use the single quote in it without needing to escape it.

Comment: @Chandral: Bro thats what I conveyed. You can either use double quotes or escape

Answer (score 0):

In requests, pass a dictionary to the data argument, the dictionary of data will automatically be **form-encoded** when the request is made.

If you need **json-encoded** data, using

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(new_user_data))
```

or

```
r = requests.post(url, json=new_user_data)
```

Refers to [More complicated POST requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Answer (score 0):

Do the following :

`import json
final_data = json.dumps(new_user_data )`

pass the final_data.